# Mostrar un tooltip en un datagridview de varias celdas seleccionadas mostrando la suma de la selección

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid, datagridview

Tengo un datagridview que cargo el contenido con `dgvSeleccion.DataSource = dtBusqueda;`
Me genera el datagridview con todos los datos, los cuales varios son numéricos.
Me gustaría que al seleccionar varias celdas de la misma columna (números) me aparezca un tooltip con la suma de lo que tengo seleccionado.
Os dejo una imagen con un ejemplo que he visto que puede servir.

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el evento CellFormatting:

```
 private void MyDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.ColumnIndex == this.MyDataGridView.Columns["id"].Index) && e.Value != null)
        {
            int suma = 0;

            //calcula la suma de los valores seleccionados
            foreach (DataGridViewCell _cell in MyDataGridView.SelectedCells)
            {
                int valor = 0;
                
                if (_cell.Value != null && int.TryParse(_cell.Value.ToString(), out valor))
                {
                    suma += valor;
                }
            }

            //Quita los valores anteriores y establece el nuevo en las celdas seleccionadas
            foreach (DataGridViewRow _row in MyDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCell _cell = _row.Cells["id"];

                if (_cell.Selected)
                {
                    _cell.ToolTipText = suma.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    _cell.ToolTipText = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

_cell.ToolTipText = null;  es importante porque al modificar la selección, las celdas se quedan con el tooltip de la última suma.

Espero haber ayudado
Saludos

[image: Captura ToolTip]

Comment: Ya lo tengo funcionando, solo que para que aparezca el tooltip tengo que entrar y salir en la celda seleccionada, no sale solo al arrastrarlas y seleccionarlas. Osea, selecciono 3 o 4 celdas, no hace nada, salgo y entro en la selección y entonces me muestra el resultado.

Comment: fantástico trabajo

Answer (score 0):

pero hay algo raro, en los tooltips me saca números aleatorios que no se ni de donde vienen.
`sSQL = "SELECT ctiID, ctiCliente [Cliente], cliNombre [Nombre], ctiUsuario [Usuario], FORMAT(ctiFAsistencia,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')[Fecha/Hora], ctiObserv [Observación], ctiMinutosDuracion [Min.], ROUND((CAST(ctiMinutosDuracion AS float))/60,2) [Horas], ctiFacturable [F]" + " FROM zzClienTiempos INNER JOIN zzClienMto ON ctiCliente = cmtCLIENTE INNER JOIN Clientes ON cliCLIENTE = cmtCLIENTE WHERE cmtTIPOMTO='SW' AND DATEPART(QUARTER,ctiFAsistencia) = '" + iTrimestre + "'";`

Cambio tu campo id por mi campo Min. y salen los números raros, adjunto foto.

[image: Foto]